# VB6 change value from positive to negative within a msaccess query

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I am so sorry for bothering you with maybe a fundamental and easy question; I need to change a positive value to a negative, this value is in the table (MSACCESS) I can´t figure out how to do it. I have been playing with the symbols but still nothing. The code is here:

```
Qry = "UPDATE QuickCash SET  Pagado = 'S', TipoPago = '" & PymntType & "' Cantidad = '" & (Abs(Cantidad) * -1) & "' WHERE Folio = '" & grdDataGrid.Columns(0).Text & "'"
```

I have been querying, then changing and then updating but that isn't very pleasant...

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does 'still nothing' mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: Don't use apostrophes to delimit data for number fields.

Comment: Still Nothing= I am getting an error in the query. I will change without apostrophes. and let you know.

Comment: What error? Edit your question.

Comment: For future reference: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Answer (score 2):

I found out the issue, I missed a semicolon and the use of symbols was wrong. Here is the correct code.

```
Qry = "UPDATE QuickCash SET  Pagado = 'S', TipoPago = '" & PymntType & "' , Cantidad = (Abs(Cantidad) * -1)  " _
    & "WHERE Folio = '" & grdDataGrid.Columns(0).Text & "'"
```

Sorry for the inconvenience, I hope this code can help someone else.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean missed a comma, there are no semicolons in your code. Sorry, I did not see that. Glad you got it working.